# Directories are empty after installation of Rtools42

Tags: r, rtools

After installation of Rtools42, I’ve noticed many directories are empty including rtools42\mingw64\bin. Whereas, rtools40\mingw64\bin are not empty.
Any idea please to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably fine.  If you start `R` and run `Sys.getenv("PATH")`, you'll probably see other directories listed in the path.  For example, I have an empty `c:\rtools42\mingw64\bin` directory, but in the path I see

```
C:\\rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin;C:\\rtools42/usr/bin;...
```

so that directory isn't being used.

I don't know why `rtools42\mingw64\bin` is being created; maybe it is needed in some special circumstances.